# VBScript to read text using shell

Tags: shell, vbscript

```
'Create a shell object
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WSCript.shell")
wshShell.Run "MyAPP.exe"

'Press tab to navigate to a radiobutton
wshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
```

I want to read the text that is displayed on the radiobutton and then click Enter. How do I read that text using shell?

Comment: Not possible with VBScript.

Comment: is there any other solution apart from VBScript?